# Error: Call to undefined function lastInsertId() when adding to cart

Tags: php

[image]
I am trying to insert into my database values from quantity and Size but I am getting Error:

> Call to undefined function `lastInsertId()` when using add to cart button that is submitting via ajax and parsed to 
>   add-cart.php

I am following an mysqli tutorial but I am using PDO and I can't find the solution for this.

I am adding my cart inside the database here:

```
  $items_json = json_encode($new_items);
  $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));
  $something=$veza->prepare("UPDATE cart SET items = '$items_json',expire_date= '$cart_expire'WHERE id ='$cart_id'");
  $something ->execute();
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,'',1,'/',$domain,false);
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);

}else {

  //add cart inside database
  $items_json = json_encode($item);
  $cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
  $smth=$veza->prepare("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('$items_json','$cart_expire')");
  $smth->execute();
  $cart_id = $smth>lastInsertId();
  setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
}
```

Comment: Look at that line...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: I am looking and still nothing...

Comment: Its missing a `-`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lastInsertId` doesn't belong to the `PDOStatement` class, but to the `PDO` instance.

```
$cart_id = $veza->lastInsertId();
```